# Looking to close a safari tab on button press with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I can close tabs/window on every browser except for Safari so far... Any idea what to do to close a Safari tab?

This is what I'm working with:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".et_pb_slide_0.et_pb_slide .et_pb_more_button.et_pb_button").on("click", function(){
            window.open('','_self').close();
        });
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `close()` method also works in safari.
[W3School close()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_close.asp)
See the browser supported by the `close()`

```
 window.close();
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately isn't working for me :( Perhaps only works on windows and not tabs?